# How to update an array of objects in local storage by adding a new property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, model-view-controller

I have an array of objects in local storage and I want to update it and add a new property "missedDays" to its objects. But it didn't add it.

I use a forEach to iterate over model.getAllStudentData() and add a new property of missed days and when I console.log(model.getAllStudentData()); it didn't add new property.

```
let model = {
    studentNames : ["Alice", "Lydia", "Adam", "Daniel", "Amy"],

    // Create attendance records if it hasn't created yet, use local storage to store them
    init: function() {
        if (!localStorage.studentData) {
            console.log('Creating attendance records...');

            /**
            * @description Create random data for our student attendanceDyas
            * @returns {boolean}
            */
            function getRandom() {
                return (Math.random() >= 0.5);
            }

            // create student object
            const studentData = [];
            this.studentNames.map(function(name) {
                const student = {};
                // add student name, addendance days
                student['name'] = name;
                student['attendanceDyas'] = [];
                // fill values of attendanceDyas array with random boolean data
                for (let day = 1; day <= 12; day++) {
                    student['attendanceDyas'].push(getRandom());
                }
                // add student object to our array
                studentData.push(student);
                return studentData;
            });

            // converts a studentAttendance object to a JSON string
            // store studentAttendance JSON string
            localStorage.studentData = JSON.stringify(studentData);
        }
    },

    getAllStudentData: function() {
        // Parse a string (written in JSON) and return a JavaScript object
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.studentData);
    }

}

/* octopus */

let octopus = {
    // get student data from model
    getStudentData: function() {
        return model.getAllStudentData();
    },

    // count missed days
    addMissedDaysAsProperty: function() {
        model.getAllStudentData().forEach((student, index, arr) => {
            arr[index]['missedDays'] = 0
            student['attendanceDyas'].map((day) => {

                if (day === false) {
                    student['missedDays']++;
                }
            });

            console.log(student, student['missedDays']);
            // return student;
        });
        console.log(model.getAllStudentData());
    },

    init: function() {
        model.init();
        view.init();
    }
}

// update I forgot to add 
octopus.init();

// console.log(octopus.addMissedDaysAsProperty());
```

The array
[{name: "Alice", attendanceDyas: [false,true, ...]}, {...}]

I expected it to add new property missedDays
[{name: "Alice", attendanceDyas: [false,true, ...], missedDays: 6}, {...}]

Comment: If you remove the console.log bit from your last line, and explicitly run model.init() just before it, you should get the result you are looking for.

Comment: It doesn't work because of the condition in the top ` if (!localStorage.studentData)`  plus I don't want to init array in local storage again. I just want to add a new property to all of its objects. @ecg8

Comment: Why results array modified in this example? `const results = [ { id:1, name: "iii" }, { id:2, name: "Rick"}]` `results .forEach((element) => { element['Active'] = [false, true]; });` and `model.getAllStudentData().forEach((student, index, arr) => { ...});` didn't